# How to create a Dynamic Error Message for server side validation in CustomValidator in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

Got my server side validation, but want to return a meaningful message to the user: for example,

"The Invoice Date must be between X and Y"

where X and Y are dates based on today's date. I made a simple version to test with that just compares the year for now. How do I get my dynamic message to appear?

```
Protected Sub cvInvDate_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)

    If IsDate(args.Value) Then
        If Year(args.Value) < Year(Today) - 2 Or Year(args.Value) > Year(Today) + 1 Then
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            args.IsValid = True
        End If
    Else
        args.IsValid = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a Label Control and set the Error Message in it:

In ASPX:

```
<asp:Label Id="ErrorMessage" runat="server" CssClass="error"></asp:Label>
```

In Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub cvInvDate_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As
    ServerValidateEventArgs)

    If IsDate(args.Value) Then
        If Year(args.Value) < Year(Today) - 2 Or Year(args.Value) > Year(Today) + 1 Then
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            args.IsValid = True
        End If
    Else
        args.IsValid = True
    End If
    If args.IsValid Then
        ErrorMessage.Text = ""
    Else
        ErrorMessage.Text = "The Invoice Date must be between X and Y"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Or** you could check out the [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx) control.

Here you only need to set the *ErrorMessage* Property and insert a new *ValidationSummary* Control:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvInvDate" runat="server" 
   CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="dpInvDate"
   OnServerValidate="cvInvDate_ServerValidate"  
   ErrorMessage="The Invoice Date must be between X and Y">*</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:ValidationSummary
   HeaderText="Error Messages:"
   runat="server"/>
```

Here is also an example of it in [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_validationsummary.asp)

**EDIT**: When the CustomValidator OnServerValidate Event fails: `args.IsValid = False`, the ErrorMessage will be shown in the ValidationSummary.

Comment: Thanks for reply victor, but I don;t see how this will solve it. my custom validator code determines the min and max dates (X and Y), so it has to set the message string. I don't to use a label, as I want all the messages displayed together in the summary.

Comment: I mean the ServerValidate Event is usualy only for validating the input. The CustomValidator contains the error message. If the input is invalid the error message is shown else not. Bellow the line the ServerValidate decides if the CustomValidator error message is shown or not. All validation error messages are listed in the ValidationSummary. So I think it's exactly what are looking for.

Comment: Still missing it. Maybe I didn't explain clearly. My custom validator is a sub, it is this sub that will define the message (i.e. insert values for X and Y based on the current date). So effectively from the sub, I need to set the CustomValidator ErrorMessage (using the dynamice values derived in my sub)

Comment: So you didn't use ASPX?

Comment: If you did, why can't you simply set `cvInvDate.ErrorMessage = "my dynamic value"`? Sry I may missunderstand.

Comment: Hi Victor. Seems I need to declare a local variable for it in my validation sub. What type would it be?

Comment: Figured it out. Worked great. Thanks for persistence Victor!